# How can we illustrate our SVN trees?

Tags: svn, tree

My team uses five separate SVN repositories, for five different modules or apps that we're maintaining. Each one has its own version sequence.

We like to **have a "wall poster" of the current state of our repos** with their branches. Currently, we're using a whiteboard for this, and it works well enough. But I'm wondering **whether a tool exists** that can help us with this? I'd be fine with having to manually update a document (Visio or whatever) but bonus points for a tool that can pull automatically from our SVN server of course.

**Our whiteboard looks roughly like this:** 
We have a main development line in the trunk `===`. When a release is complete, we tag it `o` and create a maintenance branch `---` so that we can deliver bugfix release tags `o` while trunk development continues.

```
Foo trunk:   o===dev1.0===o====dev1.1===========o====dev1.2==========
Foo 1.0.x maintenance:    |---fix1.0.1--o---    |
Foo 1.1.x maintenance:                          |--fix1.1.1--o---

Bar trunk:   o===dev1.0===o====dev1.1===========o====dev1.2==========
Bar 1.0.x maintenance:    |---fix1.0.1--o---    |
Bar 1.1.x maintenance:                          |--fix1.1.1--o---

Xyz trunk:   o===dev1.0===o====dev1.1===========o====dev1.2==========
Xyz 1.0.x maintenance:    |---fix1.0.1--o---    |
Xyz 1.1.x maintenance:                          |--fix1.1.1--o---

...
```

How do I best maintain a "poster" that looks similar to this? Note that I want to make this for several repos on a server, not just for a single repo, and that I only care about the **tags** and not about the individual checkins.

Comment: I hate to add a close vote on this, because it's a very nicely worded question with clear requirements. But seeking software tool recommendations is off-topic for this site. Such a question belongs on the software recommendations exchange: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of that site. The network grows and grows...

Comment: [Moved!](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14028/how-can-we-illustrate-our-svn-repo-trees) Should this post have been migrated instead?